# copying files to other location

Tags: shell-script, file-copy

I have multiple directories named such as:

```
15mar20a_00021sq_v01_00019en.frames
15mar20a_00021sq_v01_00020en.frames 
and so on...
```

each contains 7 files having an extension of .raw. Examples of the files in one of the directories would be:

```
IntermediateImage_20150320_180411_n0.raw
IntermediateImage_20150320_180411_n1.raw
IntermediateImage_20150320_180411_n2.raw
...until n7.raw
```

I want the script to go to each directory and copy the `.raw` files to a new directory outside of their parent directory so that I can have all the `.raw` files at the same place at the end of the whole exercise.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a little vague.  You say "I have ... directories named ..." Are these all subdirectories of one large, parent directory? Are there other subdirectories, with names not matching that scheme, that you need to ignore?  You say "I want .... copy the `.raw` files to ***a*** new directory ..." Do you mean *one* huge, new directory? Or one for each of the `.frames` directories?  And, BTW, note that `n0`, `n1`, `n2`, ..., `n7` adds up to *eight* files.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `*frames` directories are all in the same directory, you can do something like

```
cd to/the/parent/of/the/frames/dirs
mkdir all-my-raws
cp *.frames/*.raw all-my-raws/
```

To avoid duplication of files you can replace `cp` with `ln` to just create a new link to the same data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` for this.

`find /path/to/directories -type f -name "*.raw" -exec cp {} /new/path \;`

If you want to move the files instead of copying them, replace `cp` with `mv`
After moving the files you can remove empty directories with `find /path/to/directories -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;`

Comment: or link the files with `ln` or `cp -l ...`

Answer (score -1):

My proposed solution:

1. Collect list of all directories in a bash array. Something like
   `dirs=($(ls *.frames))`
   This way you will have all the directory names in an array.
2. Run a loop for the entire range with something like
   `for i in ${$dirs[@]}; do......`
3. Within the loop, create a new directory somewhere, & move all files from current directory to that location. Something like

   ```
   for i in ${$dirs[@]}; do
       mkdir dir_$i
       mv ($i)/*.raw dir_$i/
   done
   ```

This might need some minor tweaking, but pretty sure this will work.

P.S. - Try something better to create the new directories :P

Comment: This complication only if you wanted all the raw files to be in different locations. If not, Patrix's solution is simpler. I use a similar script to clean all my git repo directories.

Comment: You didn’t try this yourself, did you?  Parsing the output of `ls` (i.e., using it for subsequent command processing, rather than just displaying it) is [never a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  But your `dirs=($(ls *.frames))` suggestion is outright wrong.  Think about what you get if you type `ls *.frames` — you get a listing *of the **contents** of* the `*.frames` directories.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  So that’s what you get in your `dirs` variable when you use the `dirs=($(ls *.frames))` command.  You can fix that problem by saying `dirs=($(ls -d *.frames))` — but that breaks if any of the `*.frames` directories has a space in its name.  The ‘right’ way to do this is simply `dirs=(*.frames)` — but even that will include any files whose names match the `*.frames` pattern.

Comment: Ouch. I did say you would need some tweaking... I don't use this script to move files. And in case of dirs=(*.frames), we can have a simple check to see of it's a directory. `file $i | grep directory, if [ $? -eq 0 ] then ...... fi`

Comment: … Or simply `if [ -d "$i" ]; then …`.  By the way, it's a really good idea to quote all your shell variables unless you have a good reason not to and you're sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) Your solution is good.. Mine was relatively crude....